# Centos 7 curl error 35 and unknown cipher in list

Tags: centos, curl, openssl

I've tried to send a `GET` request to a website running `HTTPS` but always getting `curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error.` and I get this error with this only website, Youtube, Google and other sites are fine with my curl. Here is information in curl verbose mode on my server.

```
# curl -v https://***.vn > test.htm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   
  Trying 103.x.x.x:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ***.vn (103.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: none
* loaded libnssckbi.so
* NSS error -12188 (SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT)
* Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
```

I have updated my server with `yum update` and updated curl to the latest version but still not work. After that, I tried to send a request from my Macbook, when read the result, I know my curl on my Mac using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ciphers as TSLv1.2 as well.

```
Viets-MacBook-Pro:~ vietnguyen$ curl -v https://*****.vn > test.htm
* Rebuilt URL to: https://*****.vn/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to *****.vn (103.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [217 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [93 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3177 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [300 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=.....; CN=*****.vn
*  start date: Dec 11 06:22:40 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 11 06:22:40 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "*****.vn" matched cert's "*****.vn"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: *****.vn
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block
< Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 13:41:32 GMT
< Content-Length: 73711
< 
{ [7804 bytes data]
100 73711  100 73711    0     0  39172      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 39166
* Connection #0 to host *****.vn left intact
```

But when I ran curl with selected ciphers on my webserver got error `Unknown cipher in list` then even I using the latest curl version and update my webserver as well.

```
[root@localhost vietnguyen]# curl --ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 -v https://*****.vn > test.htm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.xx.xx.xx:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to *****.vn (103.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Unknown cipher in list: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (59) Unknown cipher in list: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

**My curl version**

```
# curl -V
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libpsl/0.7.0 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.31.1
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

I also run `yum update nss nss-util nss-sysinit nss-tools` to the latest nss version still not make it works.

**My openssl version**

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Can anyone has any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `unknown ciphers in list` error occurs because curl contains an internal mapping from its own set of names to the cipher names, and it's not possible to see this without looking at [the source code](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/nss.c).

Please refer to this answer: [How to convert ssl ciphers to curl format?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208437/how-to-convert-ssl-ciphers-to-curl-format/208475#208475)

The names for the `curl --ciphers` arg are on the left, the actual cipher names on the right.  The value you probably want is `ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_sha_384`.